# Как повесить действие на кнопку "Назад" в toolbar android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-toolbar

Работаю с экраном настроек в приложении и там все настройки размещены в фрагментах. В тулбаре каждого фрагмента есть кнопка возврата на главную страницу настроек, и возврат происходит нормально. Так же есть кнопка на тулбаре главного экрана настроек и я хочу на нее повесить возврат на определенный экран приложения, то есть вообще выйти из настроек. Вроде код закинул, но все-равно ничего не происходит, пробовал тост туда кинуть - все-равно глухо. Добавил слушатель выбора пункта меню который должен был работать независимо от того что находится в фрагменте, но теперь они как-то конфликтуют, и тот слушатель что в фрагменте выполняет действие которое ему не прописано. Вот какой у меня есть код на данный момент:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainScreen.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

код выше взят из главного экрана настроек, и слушатель выбора пункта меню почему-то действует на тот что находится в фрагменте. Вот что у меня есть в фрагменте:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
//bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
//bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: вы проходились дебаггером?

Comment: нет не проходился пока-что, думал может ошибка где-то на поверхности лежит

Comment: давайте тогда разбираться.

Comment: У вас есть возможность скрин экрана прислать?

Comment: Андрей, смотри, при нажатии на кнопку назад в тулбаре, у которой id - home , что-нибудь происходит?

Comment: сейчас могу попробовать, просто я не использовал этот вид активити до этого, и поэтому возникли определенные сложности. Скрин скинуть к ответу, или ссылка подойдет? и что именно нужно заскринить?

Comment: В идеале конечно к ответу, по правилам SO

Comment: дело в том что я не делал никакой кнопки с id - home, это я так понимаю id который дается по умолчанию этой стрелке

Comment: сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Давайте перейдем в чат

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83895/discussion-between-martinez-toni-and-andrew-goroshko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрали с автором его код, и пришли к выводу, что нужно переписать определенную часть.

Для работы с фрагментами выкладываю ссылку, ничего сложного нет:

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html

Дополнительно прикладываю картинку как связать работу с toolbar: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо:

```
actionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {

    startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainScreen.class));

}
```

Comment: это куда мне вставить? не в фрагменте а в главном классе? потому-что я вот пробую это использовать, и пишет что `setNavigationOnClickListener` не известная функция

Comment: вам нужен toolbar, а не actionBar

Comment: возможно он и поможет, но я пока не смог найти разметку главного экрана настроек, есть только xml файлы для работы с ними. а туда вставить тулбар нету возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Александр Соболь подсказал решение. Я его немного доработал:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```